# Location.watchPositionAsync not setting state as location

Tags: javascript, react-native, geolocation, expo

Im using expo-location to monitor my users location as it updates

The `Location.watchPositionAsync(options, callback)` function in particular.

Its outputting the correct location but its not setting that output as the state using `setLocation`

`location` is returning the following :

```
Object {
  "remove": [Function remove],
}
```

`setLocation` and `location` are being stored in a context provider

My code is as follows :

**App.js**

```
    useEffect(() => {
        console.log('hi')
        _getLocationAsync = async () => {
            let { status } = await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.LOCATION)
            if (status !== 'granted') {
                console.log('debieeed')
            }
            let locations = await Location.watchPositionAsync({ accuracy: Location.Accuracy.Balanced, timeInterval: 10000, distanceInterval: 1 }, (loc) => setLocation(loc.coords));
            console.log(locations)
           
        }
        _getLocationAsync()
    }, [])
```

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem not getting any location with `watchPositionAsync()`

It seems there is a bug (or it is intended this way, idk). **You must set accuracy to high to get location object**. It does not work with other accuracy options (as it also does not work with default).

```js
let location = await Location.watchPositionAsync(
  {accuracy:Location.Accuracy.High},
  (loc) => {console.log(loc)}
);
```

Hope this helps someone, I lost an hour on this :)

Answer (score 2):

This question is old, but for anyone still interested:

The `watchPositionAsync` function does not return the location directly; instead, it returns a **LocationSubscription** object. This object has a `remove` method that allows you to stop receiving updates. In most cases, you will use this method during the cleanup phase of the `useEffect` hook.

To receive locations, you need to provide a `callback` function as a parameter after the `options` parameter. Keep in mind that the frequency of updates depends on the values passed to the `options` parameter. During development, using high accuracy, low time intervals, and small distance intervals can be useful for testing your `callback` function. However, make sure to adjust these parameters appropriately for production.

Here's an example implementation:

```js
  useEffect(() => {( async () => {
    const { status } = await requestForegroundPermissionsAsync()
    if (status !== 'granted') {
      console.log('Permission to access location was denied')
    } else {
      const locationSubscription = await watchPositionAsync({
            accuracy: Accuracy.Highest,
            timeInterval: 1000,
            distanceInterval: 1,
      }, (location) => {
        setLocation(location)
        console.log('New location update: ' + location.coords.latitude + ', ' + location.coords.longitude)
      })
    } return () => locationSubscription.remove()
  })()}, [])
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my issue by simply making a deep copy of the location returned

**Please correct me if my logic is wrong**

I changed this

```
let locations = await Location.watchPositionAsync({ accuracy: Location.Accuracy.Balanced, timeInterval: 10000, distanceInterval: 1 }, (loc) => setLocation(loc.coords));
```

To this

```
let locations = await Location.watchPositionAsync({ accuracy: Location.Accuracy.Lowest,  distanceInterval: 2000 }, loc => setLocation(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(loc.coords))));
```

Where `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(loc.coords))` is making a deep copy of the location data

Comment: Have you had to update this for the newest expo SDK's? If so, how?

Answer (score 0):

```
export default function App() {
  const [location, setLocation] = useState(null);
  const [status, requestPermission] = Location.useForegroundPermissions();

  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      let { status } = await Location.requestForegroundPermissionsAsync();
      if (status !== 'granted') {
        setErrorMsg('Permission to access location was denied');
        return;
      }
      let location = await Location.getCurrentPositionAsync({});
      setLocation(location.coords);

      let backPerm = await Location.requestBackgroundPermissionsAsync();

      let locations = await Location.watchPositionAsync({
        accuracy: Location.Accuracy.High,
        distanceInterval: 2,
        timeInterval: 3000 
      }, 
      (loc) => { setLocation(loc.coords) });
    })(); }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Platform, Text, View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import Device from 'expo-device';
import * as Location from 'expo-location';

export default function App() {
  const [location, setLocation] = useState(null);
  const [errorMsg, setErrorMsg] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      if (Platform.OS === 'android' && !Device.isDevice) {
        setErrorMsg(
          'Oops, this will not work on Snack in an Android Emulator. Try it on your device!'
        );
        return;
      }
      let { status } = await Location.requestForegroundPermissionsAsync();


      if (status !== 'granted') {
        setErrorMsg('Permission to access location was denied');
        return;
      }

      //let location = await Location.getCurrentPositionAsync({});
      
      let  foregroundSubscrition= Location.watchPositionAsync(
    {
      // Tracking options
      accuracy: Location.Accuracy.High,
      distanceInterval: 10,
    },
   
      
       (location) => {setLocation(location);}
      
    
  )


      
    })();
  }, []);

  let text = 'Waiting..';
  if (errorMsg) {
    text = errorMsg;
  } else if (location) {
    text = JSON.stringify(location);
  }

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text style={styles.paragraph}>{text}</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    padding: 20,
  },
  paragraph: {
    fontSize: 18,
    textAlign: 'center',
  },
});
```